# gradle how to fix dependencies

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

This is what my 'app' code look like after changing it 10 times :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.adir.cool"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude module: 'support-annotations'
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
        exclude module: 'support-v13'
        exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
        exclude module: 'design'
        module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:10.0.0'
}
```

**still not wotking and giving me errors .. how should the code here look? i updated everything to the latest version.**

the errors:

```
Error:(30, 0) Cause: startup failed:
build file 'C:\Users\Adir\AndroidStudioProjects\cool\app\build.gradle': 30: Statement labels may not be used in build scripts.
In case you tried to configure a property named 'module', replace ':' with '=' or ' ', otherwise it will not have the desired effect.
 @ line 30, column 17.
           module: 'support-annotations'
                   ^

1 error

<a href="openFile:C:\Users\Adir\AndroidStudioProjects\cool\app\build.gradle">Open File</a>
```

The build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: post the errors you have

Comment: @Manza added. and after tryed the code from the user below got 3 new errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the error is :

```
Error:Cause: startup failed:
build file 'C:\Users\Robert\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build.gradle': 30: Statement labels may not be used in build scripts.
In case you tried to configure a property named 'module', replace ':' with '=' or ' ', otherwise it will not have the desired effect.
 @ line 30, column 17.
           module: 'support-annotations'
                   ^

1 error
```

Then everything you need is to modify exclusion of `support-annotations` as this line lacks word `exclude` :

Here are full dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude module: 'support-annotations'
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
        exclude module: 'support-v13'
        exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
        exclude module: 'design'
        exclude module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:10.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Giving me new errors:  Error:(23, 24) Failed to resolve: com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2
Error:(31, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0
Error:(32, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:design:24.0.0
Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0

Comment: Post main `build.gradle` too. Did you download SDK 24?

Comment: Where can if find the build.gradle?  and everytime i'm searching for sdk download it's just takes me to android studio download. i updated everything and before that i reinstalled android studio.

Comment: added the build.gradle

Comment: There is nothing wrong with `build.gradle`. Make sure you have build tools and sdk  in version 24 or later downloaded: https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html#sdk-manager

Comment: Opened a new project and still got 2 errors : Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.+
 Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2
Everything is updated to the latest version. 25.0.1

Answer (score 1):

**1.** write `exclude module: 'support-annotations'`

**2.** follow the instructions to add support libraries: 
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html

Comment: How can i know which support libraries do i need to add? i installed all the packages i have in the sdk manager

Comment: I don't understand the question, install the one you need for your application ;)

Comment: Opened a new project and still got 2 errors : Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.+
 Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2